# What letters exist in youtube video IDS

Tags: php, video, youtube

Can someone point me to the letters that exist in youtube video IDs. I know it's not just alphabet, but may contain other letters too. Do they generate them in sequence too?

If someone noticed or knows of an article that describes it, please post the link

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]`.  Fairly confident they're not sequential.

Comment: There are letters that aren't in the alphabet?

Comment: he might mean special characters, but as Frank Farmer said: pretty sure their not sequential and afaik it's just a-z, 0-9 and the _ and - signs.

Comment: @Frank a better regexp for that: `[\w\-]` -- it completely covers all of that, and in PHP it covers the underscore as well iirc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video id is an 11-character string that uses base-64 encoding which consists of Alphanumeric values, underscore and hyphen. Hope the following link would help you to get answered to your youtube related queries..

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html